# Oracle SQL query to get output in specific format

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have oracle database table 'mytable' with following data-

```
Sr_NO    Name   Status  Date
121      HP     OK     12/06/2018
122      Dell   OK     15/06/2018
123      MAC    NOK    30/07/2018
124      Apple  NOK    03/09/2018
125      MI     NOK    04/09/2018
126      Oppo   NOK    05/09/2018
127      Vivo   OK     06/09/2018
```

I want to get output in following format-

```
Category        Count   OK  NOK
Till 30th Jul   3       2   1
After 30th Jul  4       1   3
Total           7       3   4
```

Comment: Just curious - why is the cutoff July 30, and not July 31? Also, shouldn't the `Category` also show which **year** that "30th July" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the columns and `grouping sets` to get the additional row:

```
select (case when date <= '2018-07-30' then 'Till 30th Jul'
             else 'After 30th Jul'
        end) as category,
       count(*),
       sum(case when status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as OK,
       sum(case when status = 'NOK' then 1 else 0 end) as NOK
from t
group by grouping sets ( ( (case when date <= '2018-07-30' then 'Till 30th Jul'
                                 else 'After 30th Jul'
                             end)
                         ),
                         ()
                        );
```

You can add `total` as a category -- in your case -- using a comparison to `NULL`:

```
select (case when date is null then 'Total'
             when date <= '2018-07-30' then 'Till 30th Jul'
             else 'After 30th Jul'
        end) as category,
```

You have no `NULL` dates in your data, so this is fine.  Otherwise you should use `GROUPING()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,
It worked :)
I am getting output as following-
Category       Count OK NOK
Till 30th Jul 3         2 1
After 30th Jul 4         1 3
                 7         3 4

Comment: However, I was trying to add the 'Total' as Category for the total count by using

Comment: select (case when date <= '2018-07-30' then 'Till 30th Jul'
             when date > '2018-07-30' then 'After 30th Jul'
    else 'total'
        end) as category,
       count(*) as count,
       sum(case when status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) as OK,
       sum(case when status = 'NOK' then 1 else 0 end) as NOK
from t
group by grouping sets ( ( (case when date <= '2018-07-30' then 'Till 30th Jul'
             when date > '2018-07-30' then 'After 30th Jul'
    else 'total'
                             end)
                         ),
 ());
But it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Oracle keywords like `DATE` and `COUNT` as column names. I changed those to `DT` and `CT`.

This is a simple job for `GROUP BY ROLLUP`, after you create an additional column `FLAG` to show which group each row belongs to. I created the flag as `'b'` for "before July 30 2018" - otherwise the flag is NULL. (This allows me to use the flag in `ORDER BY` also, since by default ordering by `FLAG` is `NULLS LAST`.)

Remember to **remove** the `WITH` clause in its entirety before you run the query, and use your actual table and column names.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

with
  test_data (sr_no, name, status, dt) as (
    select 121, 'HP'   , 'OK' , to_date('12/06/2018') from dual union all
    select 122, 'Dell' , 'OK' , to_date('15/06/2018') from dual union all
    select 123, 'MAC'  , 'NOK', to_date('30/07/2018') from dual union all
    select 124, 'Apple', 'NOK', to_date('03/09/2018') from dual union all
    select 125, 'MI'   , 'NOK', to_date('04/09/2018') from dual union all
    select 126, 'Oppo' , 'NOK', to_date('05/09/2018') from dual union all
    select 127, 'Vivo' , 'OK' , to_date('06/09/2018') from dual
  )
select case grouping_id(flag) when 0
                              then case flag when 'b' then 'Till 30th July'
                                             else          'After 30th July'
                                   end
                              else                         'Total'
       end                                      as category
     , count(status)                            as ct
     , count(case status when 'OK' then 0 end)  as ok
     , count(case status when 'NOK' then 0 end) as nok
from   ( select sr_no, name, status, dt, 
                case when dt <= date '2018-07-30' then 'b' end as flag
         from   test_data
       )
group by rollup(flag)
order by grouping_id(flag), flag
;

CATEGORY                CT         OK        NOK
--------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Till 30th July           3          2          1
After 30th July          4          1          3
Total                    7          3          4
```

Comment: I wanted to use one more condition for 'nok' to include in 'nok' count where value in 'Status' column is NULL-
count(case status when 'NOK'  OR is NULL then 0 end) as nok

but it's not working.

Comment: @PraveenVerma - good idea, bad syntax. The correct syntax (and you **must** call `status` by name twice) is `count(case when status = 'NOK' or status is NULL then 0 end) as nok`.